# Pinyin chart which links to dictionary

Tags: pinyin, dictionary

Is there a pinyin chart which links to a dictionary? I can only find charts that link to audio files for pronunciation.

My goal is to see in one page all the characters that have the same pronunciation, e.g. xiāng, 相香箱. Preferably having a link to dictionary entries. Pleco doesn't care when I type the accented English vowel, and it lists all entries with the same spelling and any tone.

Comment: 小马词典：e.g. http://www.xiaoma.info/spy.php?py=xiang&fpy=xiang, http://www.xiaoma.info/spy.php?py=xi%C4%81ng&fpy=xi%C4%81ng, xiang1 will also work

Comment: With Pleco, you should type `xiang1`, not `xiāng`, and you will get what you’re after (just not in a chart.)

Comment: What Ming said + you can use zhuyin if you prefer xiang would be ㄒㄧㄤ - but then again first tone is not really noted so it might be harder to find all first tones this way

Comment: Thanks @Ming! Not sure why I didn't think to try that! That is very helpful. Still wish I had it in the form of a clickable pinyin chart though, surprised there isn't a web page with that. Maybe I'll try to make one.

Answer (score 1):

I have an online tool that does more or less what you want (and more).  It is based on the Unihan database, and links to it.

Here is an example with [xiang1](http://sungnyemun.org/cgi-bin/otmb.cgi?x=m%20xiang1).

It is a bit clunky -- I wrote it a long time ago, and there's a few design bugs.